# Set max length of a string c# but end with whole word

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I want to truncate text if it is too long but i need it to truncate on a whole word.  I have done the following:

```
 var mktText = model.Product.MarketingText;
            var countChars = mktText.Length;
            if (countChars > 180)
            {
                countChars = countChars - 180;
                mktText = mktText.Remove(180, countChars);
                mktText = mktText + "...";
            }
```

This code sets the max to 180 characters but will cut a word in half where i word rather have the complete word.

Any Help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's the desired output? Do you just want to add three periods?

Comment: so for example: if   wanted the  max characters to be 22 of this:
"A cat sat on a mat A cat sat on a mat A cat sat on a mat"
It would be: 
"A cat sat on a mat A c... "
but i would want it to complete the word before removing the rest:
"A cat sat on a mat A cat... "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for the last space before that position, and cut the string there. If there is no space at all, or if it is too soon in the text, then just cut it at 180 anyway.

```
string mktText = model.Product.MarketingText;
if (mktText.Length > 180) {
  int pos = mktText.LastIndexOf(" ", 180);
  if (pos < 150) {
    pos = 180;
  }
  mktText = mktText.Substring(0, pos) + "...";
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `180` where you put `150`? Not sure so didn't edit myself.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: No, I meant 150. If there is no space at all (`pos == -1`) or the space comes too soon in the text, there would be so little left of the text. In that case you just have to give up and cut the text in the middle of a word anyway. Of course it's up to the one using the code to determine how little is acceptable.

Comment: thanks @Guffa that works perfectly I will accept as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

I have found an extension method, (really I don't remember where) and now it is part of my library of extensions

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string LimitOnWordBoundary(this string str, int count)
    {
        if (str.Length <= count - 3)
            return str;
        else
        {
            int lastspace = str.Substring(0, count - 3).LastIndexOf(' ');
            if (lastspace > 0 && lastspace > count - 20)
            {
                // limits the backward search to a max of 20 chars
                return str.Substring(0, lastspace) + "...";
            }
            else
            {
                // No space in the last 20 chars, so get all the string minus 3
                return str.Substring(0, count - 3) + "...";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and now call in this way

```
string mktText = model.Product.MarketingText.LimitOnWordBoundary(180);
```

Answer (score 1):

Be very careful with the creation of strings.

Try something like this, instead:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Truncate(this string text, int length)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(text);

        var i = Math.Min(length, sb.Length);
        if ((sb.Length > length) && !char.IsWhiteSpace(sb[i]))
        {
            while ((--i >= 0) && !char.IsWhiteSpace(sb[i]))
            {
            }
        }

        if (i > 0)
        {
            while ((--i >= 0) && char.IsWhiteSpace(sb[i]))
            {
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString(0, i + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need break the text at each words. and combine the new text while checking the length.

Something like this:

```
var listWords = [ORIGINAL_TEXT].Split(' ');
var text = string.empty;
for(var str in listWords)
{
  if((text+str).Length > 180)
     break;
  text +=str + " ";
}
```

I hope the idea is clear... This code needs to be modified

Comment: sorry mistake with empty string should be CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator
or just " " :)

Comment: @VladimirShmidt: The number group separator is a comma in some cultures.

Comment: @Guffa thanks, do you know why there isn't literal constant for space?

Comment: @VladimirShmidt: Probably because it's not used frequently enough, and because it's not the only single character string that could be useful. If you had a literal for space, you would also have literals for comma, semicolon, period, dash, percent, quotation mark, apostrophe, parentheses, et.c. It would just be a bunch of strings that would always be created but seldom used.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you need, with a few minor adjustments:

***Edit:*** Adjusted to use your variables/names, and 180 for max length, etc:

```
var mktText = model.Product.MarketingText;
var cutPos = new string(mktText.Take(180).ToArray()).LastIndexOf(' ');
var result = new string(mktText.Take(cutPos).ToArray());
```